# Add custom parameter in angular-auth-oidc-client and access that in .net core identityserver4

Tags: angular, identityserver4, angular-auth-oidc-client

I want to add a custom parameter to angular-auth-oidc-client authorize method like this. With the custom parameter in this case the client_id I want to write some custom logic.

```
export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {

     constructor(private oidcSecurityService: OidcSecurityService) {
    }

     ngOnInit() {
      this.oidcSecurityService.authorize({customParams: { 'client_id': 'F93C5C9E-57DC-4889-86DD-66A98EAD94CC' } });
    }
}
```

In the backend I have setup identityserver4 in .net core 3.1 application. I have also implemented custom **ProfileService**

```
public class ProfileService : IProfileService
{
    protected UserManager<ApplicationUser> _userManager;

    public ProfileService(UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager)
    {
        _userManager = userManager;
    }

    public async Task GetProfileDataAsync(ProfileDataRequestContext context)
    {
        //>Processing
        var user = await _userManager.GetUserAsync(context.Subject);

        var claims = new List<Claim>
        {
            new Claim("FullName", user.FullName),
        };

        context.IssuedClaims.AddRange(claims);
    }

    public async Task IsActiveAsync(IsActiveContext context)
    {
        //>Processing
        var user = await _userManager.GetUserAsync(context.Subject);
        
        context.IsActive = (user != null) && user.IsActive;
    }
}
```

Also in startup.cs

```
services.AddIdentityServer()
    .AddProfileService<ProfileService>();
```

How can I access the custom parameter that is sent from angular oidc client in my .net core application?

If any additional info is needed let me know.

Answer (score 0):

IdentityServer is a certified OpenId Connect protocol implementation, Authorization request, [has predefined structure](https://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-core-1_0.html#AuthRequest), so you can't introduce *any* custom parameter you want.

According to the spec the only two "free" parameters are the `state` which is used by clients and should be sent back with response as it is, and `acr_values` which is specially aimed for sending additional parameters to the server.

**But** `client_id` is not a custom, but a standard and *required* parameter in the authorization request. So general case you just need to set it up properly.